Getting realtime/Daily converstion rates
We are considering to enable multicurrency in our org. What are the ways to keep the exchange rates in sync with market..? Do we have any products or api's that can be used to update the real-time conversion rate. Please suggest if any of you have implemented multi currency in your orgs and has managed to get real time or daily conversion rates.
We are using a managed package from conga to do contract management and the ask from business is to show amounts in Euro on the Europe region agreement record. This is why we started looking to enable multi currency , unless we have any solution to just convert a single amount field from USD to EURO using any formula functions..? if so that would be a good solution for us instead enabling multi currency.

You need to search on AppExchange and determine which solution is best for your requirements.
